# Why can I not use `csv export` with react ag grid community?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I current have my react ag grid table set up likeso:

```
// imports
...
import { AgGridReact } from '@ag-grid-community/react';
import '@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import '@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import '@ag-grid-community/csv-export';
import { ModuleRegistry } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from '@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model';
...

const onBtnExport = useCallback(() => {
  gridRef.current.api.exportDataAsCsv();
}, []);

return (
<div>
 <button variant="outlined" onClick={onBtnExport}>Excel出力</button>

 <AgGridReact
  flex={1}
  colResizeDefault='shift'
  ref={gridRef}
  rowHeight={20}
  rowData={rowData}
  rowSelection={'single'}
  columnDefs={grabColumnHeadBy(searchPage)}
  defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
  onGridReady={onGridReady}
  onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
  rowMultiSelectWithClick={true}
  pagination={true}
  suppressCsvExport={false}
  tooltipShowDelay={0}
  tooltipMouseTrack={true}>
 </AgGridReact>
</div>
);
```

I assumed that (following the react ag grid docs) that community is able to use the `download csv` api out of the box; however, I am getting this warning whenever I use the above `onBtnExport` function.

```
moduleRegistry.js:
       AG Grid: unable to use api.exportDataAsCSv as module @ag-grid-community/csv-export is not present.
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: Please read [the instructions](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/modules/#registering-ag-grid-modules) for using the modules registry.

Comment: As @AndyRay points out, the documentation tells you how to do this.
The issue is that you need to register the csv-export module before you can use it.